# How to implement a generic "saveOrUpdate" method with EclipseLink and JPA2

Tags: orm, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I'm trying to do a method like that, bug got concurrency problems.. seems like my update method do not increment the @Version attribute of my Entity.

My code is like that:

```
      @Transactional
      public B save(B bean) {
        if (bean == null || bean.getId() == null) {
            persist(bean);
        } else {
            bean = update(bean);
        }
        return bean;
      }     

      protected final B update(B bean) {
        bean = em().merge(bean);
        em().flush();
        return bean;
      }
```

This is a piece of code of my AbstractDao. The em() method return a EntityManager that is managed by Guice-Persist.

Also, I'm using eclipselink.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it with the following code:

```
protected final void persist(B bean) {
    em().persist(bean);
}

protected final B update(B bean) {
    bean.setVersion(findById(bean.getId()).getVersion());
    bean = em().merge(bean);
    em().flush();
    return bean;
}

@Transactional
public B save(B bean) {
    if (bean == null || bean.getId() == null) {
        persist(bean);
    } else {
        bean = update(bean);
    }
    return bean;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a great idea. The version number could be significanly out of date from when this thread read it, and now you are manually overwriting it with the most recent version even though it might have been legitimately stale. Instead, you can probably just use em.merge() for all cases in Save, and return the managed entity it returns for changes.  If you have version issues, try looking up the object using find before making changes rather than using a stale detached copy.